# How to make a dropdown/select required in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Okay, I have been reading a lot on this and I can't seem to find the solution.

I have a dropdown that I want to make sure someone changes/selects an answer before continuing and submitting the form. I want an alert to be thrown if they try to submit without choosing a select option.

I've tried multiple ways of required, such as:

`th:required="required"`, `th:required="true"`, `required="required"`, `required="true"`... I even tried a `@NoValidate` annotation in my model.

How can I make this drop down required? Thanks!

```html
<form  class="ui form" th:object="${directBind}" th:action="directBind" method="post"  style="padding:0 10px;">
    <h4>Customer Setup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <label >Contact Name (First/Last):</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{contactName}" required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="formAddress">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="formAddress" th:field="*{formAddress}" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="website" style="margin-top: 1em;"> Website:</label>
        <input type="text" id="website" th:field="*{website}" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="nameInsured">Name Insured:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nameInsured" th:field="*{insuredName}" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Business with Agency:</label>
        <div th:each="businessAgency : ${businessAgencies}">
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{businessAgencyList}" th:value="${businessAgency}"/>
            <label th:text="${businessAgency}">Business with Agency</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Executive:</label>
        <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
            <span th:case="false" th:text="${loggedUser.client.getExecutive()}"></span>
            <span th:case="true"> Not Applicable </span>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
            <input th:case="false" type="hidden" name="executive" class="executive" th:value="${loggedUser.client.getExecutive()}" />
            <input th:case="true" type="hidden" name="executive" class="executive" value="Not Applicable" />
        </th:block>

        <label style="font-size: 1.25rem; margin-left: 10px;">
             <input type="checkbox" id="directBox"  th:field="*{directBox}"/>
        Direct </label>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="display: inline-block; margin-top:0;">
        <p>Service Level:</p>
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="serviceLevel"  th:field="*{serviceLevel}"/>
            Affiliate Serviced</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="affiliateRep">Affiliate Designated Representative:</label>
        <input type="text" id="affiliateRep" th:field="*{affiliateRep}" required="true" />
    </div>

    <div id="amsSection">
        <h4 style="display: inline;">AMS360 Policy Setup</h4>
        <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"  name="addPolicy" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;" value="Add Another Policy Line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <hr/>

        <table class="table table-striped AMSTable" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Policy Number</th>
                <th>Policy Term Start Date</th>
                <th>Policy Term End Date</th>
                <th>Line of Coverage</th>
                <th style="width:150px;">Parent Company<i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Parent Company indicates Standard Carrier, Wholesaler, or MGA">info_outline</i></th>
                <th style="width:150px;">Writing Company<i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Writing Company indicates carrier paper specific to policy">info_outline</i></th>
                <th>Bill Type</th>
                <th>Quote Premium</th>
                <th>Commission</th>
                <th><a class="trigger btn btn-docModal"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span></a></th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr name="newRow" th:each="ams360Policy,stat : ${ams360Policies}" th:value="${stat.index}">
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyNumber}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateStart}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateEnd}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].lineOfCoverage}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].parentCompany}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].writingCompany}"/></td>
                <td id="billTypeCell">
                    <div  th:each="billType : ${billTypeList}">
                        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].billTypeOptions}" th:value="${billType}" value="off"/>
                        <label th:text="${billType}" id="billTypeLabel"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].quotePremium}"/></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].commission}"/></td>
                <td class="text-right"> <button type="Submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="removeRow" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="appendFile"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>


    <h4>PMA Setup</h4>
    <div class="row" sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')">
        <label>Sub Brand:</label>
        <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
            <span th:case="false" th:text="${loggedUser.client.getLegalName()}" ></span>
            <span th:case="true">Not Applicable</span>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null}">
            <input th:case="false" type="hidden" name="subBrand"  class="subBrand" th:value="${loggedUser.client.getLegalName()}" />
            <input th:case="true" type="hidden" name="subBrand"   class="subBrand" value="Not Applicable" />
        </th:block>
    </div>

    <!-- Business Class Drop Down Field Below: -->
    <div class="row">
        <label>Business Class: </label>
        <div >
            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{businessClasses}">
                <option th:each="businessClass : ${businessClassList}" th:value="${businessClass}" th:text="${businessClass}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="descriptionOfOps">Description of Operations:</label>
        <input type="text" id="descriptionOfOps" th:field="*{descriptionOfOps}" required="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="formFooter">
        <input id="send"  type="submit" value="send" name="send" class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Sent!" disabled="true"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you configured the `<form>` properly? The `required`, in this case, is related to HTML5, it has nothing to do with Thymeleaf.
Ex: `<select th:field="*{your_field}" required="required">`. Plus, could you post the code for us to understand it better?

Comment: @bosco , required works on text field inputs, just not on my select for some reason.

Comment: I can't see any `required` in your `select`... Also, shouldn't your form `action` be something like `th:action="@{/directBinding}"` ?